# How to filter a List in Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting my DocumentSnapshots from Firebase and I'm trying to delete the document where the user ID match but the userList is always returning the 4 records.

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> userList = new List<DocumentSnapshot>();

userList = snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot) {
  //print("ACTUAL USER :: " + docSnapshot.data['userId']);
  if (docSnapshot.data['userId'] != id) {
    return docSnapshot;
  } else {
    print('FOUND IT: ' + id);
    userList.remove(docSnapshot.data);
    //userList.removeWhere((docSnapshot) => 'userId' == id);
  }
}).toList();

print('userList Size: ' + userList.length.toString());
```

The validation works ("Found it") but none of my tests where able to delete the user from document list.

Can someone advise please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to remove the element from your `List` before it was even added.
Specifically, the `map` function will assign a `List` to your `userList` variable **after** it has mapped the snapshots.
From your code I can tell that you do not actually want to perform any *mapping* but only *filtering*.

In Dart, you can filter using the [`Iterable.where`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html).
In your case that would look something like this:

```dart
final List<DocumentSnapshot> userList = snapshot.data.documents
      .where((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['userId'] != id).toList();
```

I am assuming that you only want documents that *do not have* a `userId` of `id`, otherwise, you would have to use an `==` operator instead.

You could also use [`List.removeWhere`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html) by assigning all the documents to your `userList` first and then calling `removeWhere`:

```dart
final List<DocumentSnapshot> userList = snapshot.data.documents;

userList.removeWhere((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['userId'] != id).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying the `.removeWhere` after I create the list but was returning null too. (you have a typo on "napshot")

Comment: @FilipeOS Thanks for pointing out. [`List.removeWhere`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html) removes element from a `List` object, i.e. it transforms the `List` you call it on and does not return any result. `Iterable.where` does not transform the `Iterable` you call it on but returns its result. I added an example of how you could use `removeWhere` to my answer.